# c# inheriting Actions from base class, register and Invoke them from child classes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I looked a lot on Google but I don´t understand this. Following Sitation:

```
ParentClass 
{ 
    public Action something;
}

ClassA : ParentClass
{
    Parentclass parentclass;
    OnInitializeMethod()
    {
      parentclass = GetComponent<ParentClass>();
      parentClass.something =+ DoSomething;
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // Dosomething awesome;
    }
}

ClassB : ParentClass
{
    Parentclass parentclass;
    InitializeMethod()
    {
        parentclass = GetComponent<ParentClass>();
    }
    //Somewhere in code

    private void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        parentClass.something?.Invoke();
    }

}
```

This is working but when I then want to invoke the same Action from the parent class I got, that the Action is null.

If I do it like, what I found at google, make a Action and 2 methods, one for registering and one for Invoking, it doesn´t work. Maybe someone can tell me how it works, or better why it doesn´t work. I want to understand the logic behind it. Maybe you have some short videos on youtube or somewhere else, where it got explained.

I also tried to make it protected, but this doesn´t work. the only way how I can invoke the Action from the childclass, is make it public and reference it like a normal public action.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your parent class is of type MonoBehaviour since you are using GetComponent.
Not sure why you are using get component, since the derived class should have the Action something available to it.

```
public class ParentClass {
    public System.Action something;

    public virtual void OnInitializeMethod() { }
}

public class A : ParentClass
{
    public override void OnInitializeMethod()
    {
        something -= DoSomething;
        something += DoSomething;
    }

    void DoSomething() { }
}

public class B: ParentClass
{
    public override void OnInitializeMethod()
    {
        something -= DoSomethingElse;
        something += DoSomethingElse;
    }

    void DoSomethingElse() { }
}
```

You can then invoke the code normally

```
var b = new B();
b.OnInitializeMethod();
b.something?.Invoke();
```

You can definately make this nicer, but would need more info on what you are trying to achieve.